# Linq double group by issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am doing grouping on a single column "version" right now. Below is my query

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> data = dataTbl.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.GroupBy<DataRow, String>(d => Convert.ToString(d["version"]))
.Select<IGrouping<String, DataRow>, dynamic>(grp =>
{
return new
{
version = grp.Key,
Books = grp.Select<DataRow, dynamic>(row =>
{
return new
{
message= Convert.ToString(row["data"]),
date= row["releasedate"]

};
})
};
});
```

I want to do another group by on this result set. The above group by is on column called version. I want to add another group by column by date. Please help

Comment: Do you want to have group of groups or just group by two columns?

Comment: group of groups

Comment: Any one?? Please help me

Comment: Try Following : .GroupBy<DataRow, String>(d => Convert.ToString(d["version"]) + "^" + d["date"].Date.ToString())

Comment: Actually that won't work. I need to have a second group by on the resultset of the first group by

Comment: Do you want : .GroupBy<DataRow, KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> or GroupBy<DataRow, Dictionary<string, DateTime>>

Comment: Can you send me the complete syntax

Comment: Any body please help

Comment: Naeem - it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.  Try reading the page on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Provide some sample input and output data - preferably both your current results and the results you want.